# Use PerfMon to connect to a Remote Computer

Tags: remote, perfmon, remote-access

I want to use PerfMon to connect to a Remote Computer.  What ports do I need to have open in my Firewall to be able to connect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is port TCP/139. Check out this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017) for reference.

Comment: What I want doesn't seem too exotic - this, but the remote machine is a docker container. I'm finding zilch. Can the port just be exposed and this works all the same?

Answer (score 0):

too late to answer..but hope it will help people who are still searching

http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/09/how-to-connect-perfmon-to-remote.html